# Flex: Add one item to list using Data Binding

Tags: xml, apache-flex, list, mxml, httpservice

I am trying to load xml data into a List with Flex/MXML. I have a method for getting the XML and putting it into the list (I know that it is reading the data properly) but when I run the application I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "User1" to mx.collections.IList.
at Function/<anonymous>()[/Users/Jacob/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/App/src/views/MainMenu.mxml:52]
```

(I deleted some of the error log)

I see that it says that the error is occurring at line 52, which is the following:

```
<s:List id="xml_list" x="44" y="89" width="232" height="341" dataProvider="{get_xml.lastResult.Array.Item}"></s:List>
```

I have done some tests and I have realized that the error only occurs when the data to be added is 1 item. If there is more that 1 item then it works perfectly and puts the data in the list.

When the XML has one Item, it looks like this:

```
<Array>
<Item>Hello</Item>
</Array>
```

And When the XML has two items, it looks like this:

```
<Array>
<Item>Hi</Item>
<Item>Hola</Item>
</Array>
```

So my question is: Is there a way to solve this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: Could you post roughly what the XML look like when there is one item vs. multiple?  I couldn't reproduce the issue with my XML test, so I think there might be something with the XML you have.

Comment: @TianzhenLin Ok. I edited the above message to show my XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<s:List id="xml_list" x="44" y="89" width="232" height="341" >
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:XMLListCollection source="{get_xml.lastResult.Array.Item}" />
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

Comment: I have gotten it to work and I have posted the code I used as an Answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! I didnt understand why it doesnt work for you, but it is already not important

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it! I used the basis of the post from Serge Him, but changed his example a little. The code that I have gotten to work is:

```
<s:List id="games_list" x="44" y="89" width="232" height="341">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayCollection source="{get_games.lastResult.Games.Name}"/>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

Big thanks to Serge Him who got me pointed in the right direction!